# PHP Build from source .configure for Magento 1 and 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, server, php-5.5

I am working on a VPS machine and I want to build PHP 5.5 from source. I am kinda having an OCD of what are the PHP extensions are needed to include so that my `.configure` so that I will able to run all the functions of Magento 1(CE and EE) and Magento 2 (including Solr, Oauth, Email, Cron and etc).

currently this is my `.configure`settings

```
./configure \
    --prefix=$HOME/tmp/usr \
    --with-config-file-path=$HOME/tmp/usr/etc \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-zip \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --enable-ftp \
    --enable-exif \
    --enable-calendar \
    --enable-sysvmsg \
    --enable-sysvsem \
    --enable-sysvshm \
    --enable-wddx \
    --with-curl \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-iconv \
    --with-gmp \
    --with-pspell \
    --with-gd \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    --with-png-dir=/usr \
    --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
    --with-xpm-dir=/usr \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
    --with-t1lib=/usr \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --enable-gd-jis-conv \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-mysql=/usr \
    --with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
    --with-gettext=/usr \
    --with-zlib=/usr \
    --with-bz2=/usr \
    --with-recode=/usr \
    --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

I hope I can have also a view working `.configure` of yours :)

Comment: --enable-soap for magento 1, --emable-libxml is implicit, but you might want to show that explicitly. Otherwise I'd say the list is too large, e.g. you should be able to remove --with-mysql - Also for what it's worth, you should say which PHP version your target with that configure line. Also I would create two different configurations, one for magento 1 and one for magento 2 as the requirements will likely differ and for 2 you perhaps edit because it's easier to re-use libraries.

Comment: @hakre i added the php version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1.x PHP requirements, CentOS: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_req-prereq_centos.html#php-extensions

Magento 1.x PHP requirements, Ubuntu: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_req-prereq_ubuntu.html#php-extensions

Magento 2 system requirements: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html